# what will happen if assign a weak property to a strong property?

Tags: objective-c, retain, autorelease

In old term, it's about assign a autoreleased property to a retain property. What will happen if do that, something like the following does.

```
@property(strong, nonatomic) NSString *new;

... 

NSString *old = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@"), @"hello", @"world"];
new = old;
```

Comment: Then that instance got retained once, period. BTW, in your example, `old` is still a strong instance, and by default, an instance of object is strong.

Comment: ok. any example for a weak object?

Comment: for a pointer to be weak you have to explicitly declare it as so. NSStrings are autoreleased by default so this is not an instance of a weak pointer. If you do create a weak pointer, it will not retain whatever it is pointing to. If there is only one other pointer that points to it and it gets released, the object will be deallocated and the weak pointer will be dangling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adding to my comment on your question:

read this

[Variable Qualifiers](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html)

It describes the different types of lifetime qualifiers you can declare variables with and gives examples of each.

**Edit with relevant bits:**

The lifetime qualifiers you can use are:

> __strong
>
> __weak
>
> __unsafe_unretained
>
> __autoreleasing

Their descriptions are in the docs but I will go into the first 2.

`__strong` is the default type (when you don't specify one) and it will increase the retain count of the object by 1. As long as there is a strong pointer pointing to an object, it will remain alive.

`__weak` does not increase the retain count of an object and will not keep it alive. If there are no strong references pointing to the same object, the weak pointer will be set to nil automatically. (`__unsafe_unretained` is actually almost the same as weak but they are left dangling instead of being set to nil).

If you create an object immediately assigned to a weak pointer, it will be instantly deallocated since there are no strong references to it.

Sample Code from docs:

```
NSString * __weak string = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"First Name: %@", [self firstName]];
NSLog(@"string: %@", string);
```

The value of `string` will be null when trying to print it in this case.

You can only use a weak pointer if the object you want to reference with it already has at least one strong reference to it. Otherwise the (new) object will be deallocated instantly.